# Battery failing on Acer Aspire One 722 when starting

Tags: power-management, startup, battery, acer

I have been running Ubuntu 13.04 on my Acer about month ago, it has worked perfectly, but some days ago the battery hasnt allowed the computer to start. It starts normally with the computer connected and without the battery. A friend told me that it could be the battery that is failing. But it never happened before when using Windows 8. I am not saying that Windows is better because in fact I love Ubuntu; but I don't want to buy a new battery which could present the same problem. 
Apologize my English, I am an ignorant on this and that's the reasong why I'm asking; thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Different operating systems put different loads on the battery at different times. Although, in general, Linux uses less power overall, it could be asking your machine to do multiple things at once which generate a greater load from the battery. The Linux load shows your battery's capacity is declining, and me, I have no doubt, the problem will appear with Windows 8 soon, for certain.